# NodeJS - synchronized http.request or child_process.exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization

I am familiar with the strength of an asynchronous execution, and I know how to use callbacks. Though, for few reasons, I wish to execute some portion of code in a synchronized manner. For instance, `http.get()` and `child_process.exec()`.

Note that both examples mentioned above must be utilized with event listeners (`on(...)`) in order to collect results and handle errors.

Any chance that one could shed light on the issue.
A small snippet will be great (for instance, synchronized `http.get()` with its even handling)

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I am able to use `httpsync` in order to produce a request and capture the response. The response itself is a `buffer`. I am using `httysync` to retrieve few images, but when writing the buffer to file (using `fs.writeFile`), the image can not be open. I guess it has to do with some conversion of the file. So if one can help with solving this, then it solves the issue.

enclosed a snippet

```
var httpsync = require("httpsync");
var fs = require("fs");
var req = httpsync.get({ url : "http://www.tunisia-live.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/christmas-tree-wallpaper1024x768.jpg" });
var res = req.end();
fs.writeFile("out.jpg", res.data, function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Async tasks *cannot* be executed synchronously. For what reasons do you want that?

Comment: @Bergi, let's not get into philosophy. i have depicted what i wish to achieve, just thought one can help me achieving it.

Comment: @Bergi, i have placed a snippet in my original post. can you please take a look?

Comment: Hm, ok. So what is the error that happens with the code? What do you mean by "*the image can not be open*"?

Comment: @Bergi, i guess the image "encoding" is incorrect. i.e., it produces an invalid image.